# Stationary Points of a graph with fractions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the stationary points of the graph $y=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}$ and determine the nature of each. 
I have differentiated but as there are x's to negative powers i dont see how it can be factorised in a way that is still usable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: use that $$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^3}$$ and by the quotient rule we get
$$f'(x)=\frac{(2x+1)x^3-(x^2+x+1)3x^2}{x^6}$$
simplifying this we obtain $$f'(x)=\frac{-x^4-2x^3-3x^2}{x^6}$$
and we get $$f'(x)=-{\frac {{x}^{2}+2\,x+3}{{x}^{4}}}$$ this deriavtive is negative and your function monotonuoulsy decreasing for all $x\neq 0$

Comment: Easier, I think, to differentiate first and then find a common denominator.

Comment: And i think your way is not easier.

Comment: Well I would (for benefit of OP) differentiate the monomials to get $-x^{-2}-2x^{-3}-3x^{-4}$ and avoid using the quotient rule.

Comment: If i was to use the initial hint by Dr Graubner how would you use that to get the stationary points would you do the top and the bottom separately or all together.

Answer (score 0):

Quotient rule derivative gives

$$\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{x^3}=\dfrac{2 x +1}{3 x^2} $$

cancel $x^2$ in denominator $ x \ne 0$ , cross multiply, transpose and simplify to get

$$ x^2 + 2x +3= 0 $$

original expression is monotone increasing because discriminant of above quadratic equation

$$\Delta= 4-4\cdot 3\cdot 1<0 $$